# forced to add android.r and activity_main cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android

I have downloaded the project from this website:
http://www.easyway2in.blogspot.ae/2014/07/android-swipe-views-example.html

Somehow, activity_main cannot be resolved. Whereas my other projects work just fine.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.swapdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ViewPager viewpager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        PagerAdapter padapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
          viewpager.setAdapter(padapter);
    }


}
```

I have tried importing 'android.R' but that just gets 'activity_main cannot be resolved' message. All I did was add the support for v7-appcompat and nothing more. I have tried cleaning it for countless times. Anyone, help?

Comment: Where does your layout file exist? It should be in the `layout` folder

Comment: the layout is in the layout folder. like i said on top, i changed NOTHING. try it yourself.

Comment: check activity_main.xml exist in res/layout folder if so then try clean project or restart eclipse.

Comment: @user3787761 , I have downloaded and launched the project at the indicated link. No problems.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're importing the correct resources, **`android.R`** is referring to the Android resources, what you're looking for are the resource of "your project" since that's where your layout file is at, your R should be pointing to **`com.swapdemo.R`**